# Moldy looking soil in my greenhouse

Tags: soil, mold

I have had moldy looking soil in my greenhouse for the last couple of years. It looks like fine dust on top of the soil. My greenhouse is well ventilated and I have used various fungicides with no results.
Anyone got any advice?
Thanks [image]

Comment: The symptoms on the plants are similar to those of Botrytis cinerea? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botrytis_cinerea

Comment: What is 'well ventilated'?  If you have proper ventilation your hair will be massively blowing around.  I am serious. What temperatures does your green house get up to?  Are you able to open up the bottom 'flaps' windows?  Have you made 'beds' in your greenhouse out of the original soil? You will never get rid of botrytis, it is everywhere.  Very normal.  The use of fungicides on your soil is not good.  The beauty of using your own garden soil is that you have a huge body of organisms that keep each other in check.  To kill all fungus will cause more fungal problems. They don't tell you that.

Comment: Where do you live?  How do your plants look?  Are you using this soil to grow plants in?  Which is the best use of the greenhouse...please send more information and pictures.

Comment: Try just raking the surface with a metal leaf rake.  Sometimes that is all it takes to discourage fungus on the surface of the soil or mulch.